# Put a Label and a TextField in a same row

Tags: java, swing, grid-layout

I would like create a calculator in Java Swing but I have a problem I want to put one label and one textfield in same row, not two columns but in the same row ex: Number 1:(label) (textfield here) in a same row, sorry for my English.

My code :

```
private JPanel mainPan; //= new JPanel();
private JLabel title;
private JLabel nb1;
private JLabel nb2;
private JButton button;
private JTextField textField; //= new JTextField();

public Fenetre() {
    super ("Calculator");
    mainPan = new JPanel();
    title = new JLabel();
    nb1 = new JLabel();
    nb2 = new JLabel();
    button= new JButton();
    textField = new JTextField();

    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 500));
    setSize(400, 500);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(Fenetre.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(true);

    setIconImage(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\sidot\\Desktop\\download.png").getImage());

    mainPan.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
    mainPan.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,0));
    Border border = LineBorder.createBlackLineBorder();


    title.setText("Calculator 1.0");
    title.setFont(new Font("MONOSPACED", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    title.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    title.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
    title.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
    title.setBorder(border);
    mainPan.add(title);

    nb1.setText("Number 1");
    nb1.setFont(new Font("MONOSPACED", Font.BOLD, 15));
    nb1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    nb1.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.LEFT);
    nb1.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
    nb1.setBorder(border);
    mainPan.add(nb1);

    nb2.setText("Number 2");
    nb2.setFont(new Font("MONOSPACED", Font.BOLD, 15));
    nb2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    nb2.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.LEFT);
    nb2.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
    nb2.setBorder(border);
    mainPan.add(nb2);

    this.setContentPane(mainPan);
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

I want have after number 1 and number 2 a textfield.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default layout for a `JPanel` is the `FlowLayout`. So you can use a `JPanel` to hold the label and text field:

```
JPanel rowPanel = new JPanel();
rowPanel.add( label1 );
rowPanel.add( textField1 );
mainPanel.add( rowPanel );
```

The main point is you can nest panels with different layout managers and components to achieve your desired layout. Read the section from the swing tutorial on [Layout Manger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks you, it works but it's not align The "number1" and the textfield is on top of the rowPannel, how can i change this and place it on center left of this rowPannel ?

Comment: Did you read the `Layout Manager` link I provided your with? The section on `How to Use FlowLayout` explains how you can do this. Or did you read the `FlowLayout` API? You can change the alignment to be left aligned. Or maybe you need to use a more complicated layout manager like the GridBagLayout. I don't understand your exact requirement. When you read tutorials you find out more information than by asking questions one at a time. Take advantage of the tutorial and keep the link handy for other Swing basics.